# Image in related record won't display on index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, activerecord

I have 2 tables, one of venuetypes and one of mapicons. A venuetype belongs to a mapicon.

Each mapicon has a name and an image uploaded with paperclip.

When I view a venuetype record I have the associated mapicon displayed using this bit of code:

```
<%= image_tag @venuetype.mapicon.mapicon.url(:mapicon) %>
```

I have another table of venues where each venue belongs to a venuetype.

However when I view a venue record on the index page the mapicon doesn't display the image, it just shows as a blank div with the properties set in the css class.

This is the code im using to atempt to display the mapicon:

```
<div id="venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>" style="position:absolute;" <%= image_tag (venue.venuetype.mapicon.mapicon.url(:mapicon)), :class => "mapicon" %></div>
```

I hope my question makes sense, I wil try clarify if needed, thanks for any help its much appreciated!

**edit**

**mapicon model**

```
class Mapicon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :venuetypes
  has_attached_file :mapicon,
    :styles => {
      :mapicon => "20x20" }
end
```

**venuetype model**

```
class Venuetype < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :venues
  belongs_to :mapicon
  has_attached_file :icon,
    :styles => {
      :thumb=> "100x100>",
      :small  => "150x150>",
      :medium => "300x300>",
      :large =>   "400x400>" },
      :default_url => '/images/noimage.png'
end
```

**venue model**

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :addressline1, :addressline2, :addressline3, :addressline4, :postcode, :phonenumber, :about, :icontoppx, :iconleftpx, :area_id, :venuetype_id, :lat, :long, :venuephotos_attributes
  belongs_to :area
  belongs_to :venuetype
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :venuephotos

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :venuephotos, :allow_destroy => true

  scope :with_type, lambda { |types|
    types.present? ? where(:venuetype_id => types) : scoped }

  scope :with_area, lambda { |areas|
    areas.present? ? where(:area_id => areas) : scoped }

  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{name.gsub(/\W/, '-').downcase}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please post the code from your models that shows the association declarations for venuetype, venue and mapicon, and the paperclip declaration for mapicon?

Comment: @Yardboy, thanks for having a look I've added the models to my question

Comment: Sorry for so late getting back to this. Bad week. Hrm... well that didn't help, I don't see any obvious issues with your models and associations. How about this piece: <div id="venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>" - are you finding that venue.id is resolving correctly in this first part of that line of code?

Comment: @Yardboy, thanks for getting back, yea the ID is displaying fine, the icon is clickable and links to the correct venue.

Comment: @Yardboy, I've sort of fixed it, I duplicated the image_tag in that line of code so it reads: <div id="venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>" style="position:absolute; background:<%= image_tag (venue.venuetype.mapicon.mapicon.url(:mapicon)) %> <%= image_tag (venue.venuetype.mapicon.mapicon.url(:mapicon)), :class => "mapicon" %></div> and it works, although this isn't how I'd like to have it written any ideas as to what I've done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAH! I think I see it, if this is it we'll be kicking ourselves...

Your view tags are jumbled:

<`div id="venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>" style="position:absolute;" <%= image_tag (venue.venuetype.mapicon.mapicon.url(:mapicon)), :class => "mapicon" %></div>`

It's missing a closing ">" on the first div, and also the closing parentheses on the image_tag call is misplaced. It should be after "mapicon", as such:

```
<div id="venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>" style="position:absolute;">
<%= image_tag(venue.venuetype.mapicon.mapicon.url(:mapicon), :class => "mapicon") %>
</div>
```

Unless "mapicon" class is supposed to be on the div, in which case it would look like this:

```
<div id="venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>" style="position:absolute;" class="mapicon">
<%= image_tag(venue.venuetype.mapicon.mapicon.url(:mapicon)) %>
</div>
```

I think the single-line horizontal scroll display messed with my head and prevented me from seeing it. When I saw your workaround in paragraph form, it jumped right out at me.

Hope this is it. :)

Comment: that did it! The mapicon class is on the div it works great, thanks so much!

Comment: Excellent. Now I can sleep at night. ;)